# Grep Multiple Files with Dates in FileName for Certain range of Dates

Tags: grep, filenames, wildcards

I have a bunch of files with filenames like "Logger.2018-08-04_23:59:59.csv" and I want to grep a bunch of them at once, but only in a certain date range, e.g. 8/04-8/17.  How can I do this?

I tried:

```
grep "string" Logger.2018-08-[04-17]*.csv
```

but that turned up results from 8/2 and not some from 8/13-8/17.
I can do it in two parts with

```
grep "string" Logger.2018-08-0[4-9]*.csv Logger.2018.08-1[0-7]*.csv
```

And that works, but is there a better way for longer date ranges so I don't have to keep adding file chunks every time I need to increment the first digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of find with a regular expression to narrow your candidate files to the date range you want and then pipe the result to grep. Adjust the portion of the regex contained in paranthesis to change your date range. Example:

```
$find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*Logger.2018-08-((0[4-9])|(1[0-7])){1}.*' -exec grep -l text '{}' \; | sort -n -t- -k3

./Logger.2018-08-04_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-05_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-06_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-07_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-08_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-09_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-10_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-11_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-12_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-13_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-14_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-15_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-16_23:59:59.csv
./Logger.2018-08-17_23:59:59.csv
```

In this case I used grep's "-l" option to list the resulting files instead of the dummy text to show that it indeed limited the grep to the files that you want. To actually see your grep text line remove the "-l". I also added an additional pipe to sort to make the output pretty.

PS I have found the site [regex101](https://regex101.com/) valuable for playing around with and learning regex.

Comment: Thank you (I got it to work after some user error) and thank you for the link! That will be super useful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `bash` with "extended pattern matching"? Try

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -la Logger.2018-08-@(0[4-9]|1[0-7])*.csv
```

Comment: How about the 10th?

Comment: @JeffSchaller That is an unlucky day.  We do not speak of it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller; thanks for correcting my typo...